# sub-algebra of continuous real valued functions without unit must vanish at a point

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $A$ a closed subalgebra ( a vector space and closed under multiplication) of $C( X \to \mathbb R)$ the set of continuous real valued functions which separates points, and $A$ does not contain the unit. How can I prove that that there must exists a $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$ for all $f \in A$.

---

This is a part of my bigger problem. I got stuck here. My approach is if for any $x \in X$, there exists a $f_x \in A$ such that $ f_x (x) \neq 0$, then we have an open neighbourhood of $x$ that $f$ does not equal to $0$ on it. Since $X$ is compact we can have a finite cover of $X$ of this open sets. Thus we have $f_1,...f_n$ each not equal to $0$ on an open set which the union covers $X$. And let $ f = f_1^2+...+f^2$ we have $ f > 0$ for all $X$, and $f \in A$.

This is as far as I can get. I want to take $ f * \frac{1}{f} = 1$ to get a contradiction but I don't know how $ \frac{1}{f}$ is in $A$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't we need *proper* subalgebra?

Comment: Sorry, forgot one important condition, fixing

Comment: @NajibIdrissi But it's not closed right? Is it?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Well, the closed I mean here is the closed in metric space of $C(X \to \mathbb R)$ with the sup-norm.

Comment: Ah! Since you had written just after "a vector space and closed under multiplication", I thought this is what "closed" referred to (which in hindsight was a bit weird, but...). This problem got a lot more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I'm assuming that your $A$ is closed with respect to the supremum norm)*

Take your $f$. As $f$ is continuous, its image is a compact subset of $(0,\infty)$. In particular, $e>f(x)>d>0$ for some fixed $e,d$ and all $x\in X.

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence of polynomials on $[d,e]$ that converge uniformly to $t\mapsto1/t$. with the additional property that $p_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ (this can be achieved by approximating a continuous function on $[0,e]$ that his $0$ at $0$ and that agrees with $1/t$ on $[d,e]$). As $A$ is an algebra, $p_n(f)\in A$ for all $n$. As the convergence is uniform, $\{p_n(f)\}$ is Cauchy in $A$ and it converges to $1/f$.

Then $1\in A$, and that is your contradiction. Thus there exists $x_0\in X$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ for all $f\in A$.

Comment: I've thought about this. But since $A$ does not have the constants, $p_n (f) $ may not in $A$.

Comment: But maybe I can try to approximate $ \frac{1}{t}$ using polynomials without constant. Maybe that's a way to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I was about to tell you that. Instead of approximating $1/t$ on $[d,e]$ you approximate a continuous function on $[0,e]$ that is $0$ at $0$ and agrees with $1/t$ on $[d,e]$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!